# JS ES6 How to sort array by own template?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i have trouble.
I have got array with uniq value (no repeats), but ever different length. For example I get this 
1)array:

```
['asd', 'asa','wsz', 'xssa', 'asad', 'casde']
```

it must sort to:

```
['wsz', 'asa', 'xssa', 'casde', 'asad', 'asd']
```

2)array:

```
['asd', 'asa', 'xssa', 'asad', 'casde']
```

and it must sort to:

```
['asa', 'xssa', 'casde', 'asad', 'asd']
```

3)Array:

```
['asd', 'asa','wsz']
```

and it must sort to:

```
['wsz', 'asa', 'asd',]
```

The sorting sequence should always be as in the first `['wsz', 'asa', 'xssa', 'casde', 'asad', 'asd']`. If the element is smaller, then they simply will not, but the sequence will remain.

How I can create template for my own values and гse them regardless of the size of the array (the size is always less than the size of the template)?

Comment: It's difficult to understand what the sorting mechanism you're trying to achieve is. Beyond that, this – sorting arrays – is a simple programming problem, you should have some at least executable code that demonstrates what approach you have taken to solve the issue.

Comment: what means "*If the element is smaller*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make a map object that use the string as the key and the order number as the value. Use `sort()` to sort the array using the temporary object.

```js
let order = ['wsz', 'asa', 'xssa', 'casde', 'asad', 'asd'];
let temp = order.reduce((c, v, i) => Object.assign(c, {[v]: i}), {});

let arr = ['asd', 'asa', 'xssa', 'asad', 'casde'];

arr.sort((a, b) => temp[a] - temp[b]);

console.log(arr);
```

`sort()` needs to loop thru each element and compare each one. One option to avoid `sort()` is to make a `new Set` of your array. Then using `filter()` check each element of `order` array. If the element exists on the Set object, add to the new array.

```js
let arr = ['asd', 'asa', 'xssa', 'asad', 'casde'];
let map = new Set(arr);

let order = ['wsz', 'asa', 'xssa', 'casde', 'asad', 'asd'];

let newArr = order.filter(o => map.has(o));

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use template.indexOf inside your sort function to locate the position of elements from data in template.

```js
var template = ['wsz', 'asa', 'xssa', 'casde', 'asad', 'asd'];

var data1 = ['asd', 'asa','wsz', 'xssa', 'asad', 'casde'];
var data2 = ['asd', 'asa','wsz']; 

function sortFunc(a, b) {
  return template.indexOf(a) - template.indexOf(b);
}

data1.sort(sortFunc);
data2.sort(sortFunc);

console.log(data1);
console.log(data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sort() function using callback, where the condition will be indexes of your original array.

```
function sortMyArray(a, b) {
  let array = ['asd', 'asa','wsz', 'xssa', 'asad', 'casde'];
  if (array.indexOf(a) < array.indexOf(b)) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

let myarray = ['wsz', 'asa', 'asd',];
myarray = myarray.sort(sortMyArray);
```